# DropDownList em Cascata MVC 4

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

View:

```
<asp:Content ID="Javascript" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">        
    $(document).ready(function () {            
        $("#estados").change(function () {
            var uf = listaCidade($(this).val());

        });            
    });        
    //chamada ajax para a Action ListaCidade        
    //passando como parâmetro a Estado selecionado        
    function listaCidade(uf) {

        // <%=Url.Action("listaCidade")%>
        $.getJSON('/AdmPaginaBranca/listaCidade/' + uf, listaCidadeCallBack);

    }
    //função que irá ser chamada quando terminar        
    //a chamada ajax 

    function listaCidadeCallBack(json) {

        //Limpar os itens que são maiores que 0            
        //Ou seja: não retirar o primeiro item  
        $("#cidades:gt(0)").remove();

        $(json).each(function (id, nome) {
            //adicionando as opções de acordo com o retorno  
            //alert(data);

            $("#cidades").append("<option value='" + this.id + "'>" + this.nome + "</option>");
        });            
    }   
</script>
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult listaCidade(int id)
    {
        cidadeEstadoDAO obj = new cidadeEstadoDAO();


        var estado = obj.CarregarComboCidade(id);

       var data = estado.Select(m => new { m.id, m.nome }).ToList();

        return Json(new { Result = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Estou com o seguinte problema: quando eu seleciono o estado na `dropdownlist`, ele chama o método normalmente e faz o *select* no banco (verifiquei pelo "inspecionar elemento") porém, na `dropdown` da cidade, ele está vindo com o valor *undefined*. Quando coloco um `alert` no "id" ou no "nome" aparece *undefined* também.

Alguma alma caridosa pode me ajudar?

Comment: Verifique o nome dos atributos. Caso esteja errado (até mesmo uma letra minúscula no lugar errado). Tente acessar a `action` pelo browser e veja o retorno.

Comment: ja tentou fazer um `return Json(data, JsonRequest...)` direto?

Comment: então, acho que o problema não está no método e sim no código jQuery, verifiquei a action pelo browser e está trazendo tudo.. "Result: [{id: 1200013, nome: "Acrelândia"}, {id: 1200054, nome: "Assis Brasil"},…]".. acredito que o problema esteja na hora de jogar a lista na dropdown.. esqueci de mencionar.. eu nao manjo nada de javascript/jQuery kk, entao vou pedir paciencia de voces

Comment: @RodrigoDetomini Já fez o *debug* desse JS?

Comment: @ Maicon Carraro muitissimo obrigado pela dica! era esse o motivo que não estava retornando da controler!.. fiz direto como voce falou e funcionou que é uma beleza!!! muito obrigado a todos que ajudaram!

Answer (score 2):

Colocando como resposta a solução que indiquei nos comentários.

Na linha do seu retorno você não precisa criar um novo encapsulamento, altere a linha:

```
return Json(new { Result = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Para

```
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```